# I am not getting any syntax error highlights in VSCode and other errors

Tags: .net, macos, visual-studio-code, f#

I am learning F# syntax for my interview in a few days. I am not getting any syntax error highlights where I should be. Also, some lines of code works, other do not.

I am on:

1. VSCode Version 1.63.2 (Universal)
2. MacOs 12.2
3. Ionide-FSharp is installed
4. dotnet version 5.0.404

This works:

```
let mutable a = 10
a <- 20 //chaning a to 20
a //a is now 20

let items = [1..5] //creates list from 1 to 5
List.append items [6] //adds 6 to list of 6 --does not change 'items'
```

This does not work:

```
let prefix prefixStr baseStr = 
    prefixStr + ", " + baseStr

prefix "Hello" "World"
```

returns:

```
Microsoft (R) F# Interactive version 11.4.2.0 for F# 5.0
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All Rights Reserved.

For help type #help;;

> let prefix prefixStr baseStr = ;;

  let prefix prefixStr baseStr = ;;
  -------------------------------^^

/Users/MyName/Documents/learnf#/stdin(1,32): error FS0010: Incomplete structured construct at or before this point in binding
> # silentCd @"/Users/MyName/Documents/learnf#";;
- # 1 @"/Users/MyName/Documents/learnf#/001_fsharp_1.fs"
- ;;
```

Comment: Why did you type two semicolons after the first line? Two semicolons indicate the end of a "complete construct", in this case a `let` block.

Comment: @Fyodor, I do not. When i hit “option + /“, it returns my code with two semicolons. 

Unless there is two invisible semicolons in my code, I have no idea how to fix that

Comment: Ah, you didn't say how you were running those lines. Don't hit option+/ on every line separately. Select all lines and then hit option+/

Comment: That is what I did. the top block of code I can individually and it worked. The second block of code ```let prefix prefixStr baseStr = 
    prefixStr + ", " + baseStr

prefix "Hello" "World"``` When I highlight the whole thing, it gives me the error in the post. Also, in the output window in VSCode, I only have an option for F# and not F# Interactive

Comment: Nevermind, I figured it out. Option + / sends line. Option + Enter sends selection

Comment: You may find it easier to work with F# notebooks when learning the language. It's excellent when you just want to iterate on a small piece of code. [A blog about it.](https://www.compositional-it.com/news-blog/a-brief-introduction-to-f-notebooks/). [A video about it.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_QnbV6CAWXc&t=1298s)

Answer (score 0):

You're only sending the first line of your code to fsi.

Use your cursor to highlight all of this:

```ml
let prefix prefixStr baseStr = 
    prefixStr + ", " + baseStr

prefix "Hello" "World"
```

Then hit alt+enter. It will send all 4 lines at once and give you what you want.